# How to Install Ubuntu 23.04 instead of Ubuntu 22.04 (keeping all apps + files)

Tags: boot, system-installation, software-installation, update-manager, 23.04

So I am running Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 and want to upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04 keeping all files **AND** apps. I know it is possible to keep all files, but is it possible to keep all apps also? I want to do this because I have multipal applications that have special settings that would be lost if reseting the system. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you read the answer I've tagged above; I'm on a box I purchased earlier this year, and have already re-installed once since my initial install, without losing any files; but have done it many times this year on many boxes.

Comment: FYI: This machine was actually a Lubuntu install, but on my re-install I had issues with `calamares` (installed user by Lubuntu), and as I wanted this box back to operational, I just used the Xubuntu ISO instead (it used the `ubiquity` installer) to bypass my issue & get it back operational that way... The different Ubuntu ISOs (Xubuntu, Lubuntu) just install different packages as directed by *seed* files, so post-install (*with Xubuntu media*) I just turned it into what I actually wanted..

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop is available with two installers (`ubuntu-desktop-installer` & `ubiquity`)...   You are aware that Ubuntu 23.04 is already in *countdown* to EOL, with it's replacement release already *stable* and/or released... I'd re-install a system that wasn't in its last months of support.  *You didn't mention if apps are Ubuntu repository software or 3rd party, as it matters*